# Sorting multiple attributes of lists at a time in python?

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

I have a tuple  that represents a person contains an (ID, overall score, days employed, peer score).

I have decided to put each tuple in a list as follows:

```
aList = [ aTup, bTup, cTup.....]
```

I would like to rank people from best to worst based on the rules below.
The rules are as follows:

```
1. People(in this case the tuples) are sorted based on their overall score.
-->If the overall score is the same, sort it by the number of days employed. 
-->If the days employed is the same, sort by peer score.
-->If the peer score is the same, sort by ID(the smaller ID gets preferenced.
```

Is there a method in python that allows me to achieve this? Something close to the .sort() method?

Answer (score 1):

The default `sort()` actually does that for tuples. You only need to make sure that your tuples are of the form `(score, days_employed, peer_score, id)`.

Comment: What if my tuple has other information that I don't need to sort, but need later on? What should I do to handle that case?